# Execute Command in Binary String Format in Python3

Tags: python, pwntools

I am retrieving simple assignment commands from a remote terminal connection in Python, and would like to execute them. The format will be like `b = 3156`, and I would like to execute it using `exec()`. My code:

```py
def execbin(cmd):
    exec(cmd.decode('ascii')) # decode() because recvline() gets a binary string

conn = remote(url, port) # this is from the library pwntools
execbin(conn.recvline(keepends=False)) # get the line and run it
```

However, the assignment to the variable is not taking place:

[image]

How can I successfully execute this assignment?

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote something like:

```py
def getval(cmd):
    return eval(cmd[4:])

b = getval(conn.recvline(keepends=False))
```

and it worked. This question is still open for better answers!